# CSS div width auto

Tags: css

```
div {
    width: auto;
}
```

Hello, I got a very small question about width! This code fixes the width of a div automatically but is there a way to give it a plus 10 pixels the above automated width? I tried `width: auto + 10px` but didn't work...

Comment: you can add padding:10px

Comment: padding would do the job

Answer (score 2):

Value **auto** sets the value to 100% of the **Parent** container. If you want `100% + 10px` same as `auto + 10px` then use `calc`.

```css
#parent{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#child{
  background-color: green;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `width: 100%` =/= `width: auto`

Comment: so if someone using auto he can't follow the above code

Comment: auto value is calculated by the browser. When you set the width of a div to auto browser calculates it to be the 100% of the parent width. here is a pen proving that: http://codepen.io/kazx/pen/EWyejj

Comment: So If the questioner got a div with its width set to auto that means it's taking a 100% width of the parent container and if the questioner wants to increase that width by 10px then my answer is right and on point.

Comment: look, `width: auto` is `100%` by default but it also includes `borders, margins, paddings, e.t.c`  
but on other hand when you set `width: 100%` it would be of your content, and if you add some `paddings, margins` then it would be content+padding or `100%(content) + (paddings/margins)` 
so it would take more than `100%` for a content with margins or paddings

Comment: hope you got it

Comment: @HassanZia stop making this question more complicated for others. Calculation of a div's size can be changed to include padding & borders with `box-sizing` property or we can exclude them with this. Margin isn't a part of it. Its just the empty space around the box.

Comment: and I posted my answer cause your answer was essentially a hack. It works but wasn't the right way.

Comment: @Ahmad i ain't making this complicated, i just pointed out the difference between `auto` and `100%` . and my answer did what OP required so it's enough, moreover I remained to what he asked about. 
yet i agree you did it in more practical way but i just tried to clear how `auto` works

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing I tend to think in different cases you could both be right depending on the box-sizing..

Comment: thnx for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Solution to OP's problem:

```
div {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 5px; /* This would add a padding of 5px to both the left and the right of the div content box, which gives an additional 10px to the total width of the element. */
}
```

this would do the job

For more information: [Introduction to the CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)

---

**EDIT (Difference between width:100% and width:auto)**

I've use same styling for both `divs`but you can see the difference.

```css
.main{
  margin:auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid thin green;
}
.sub1{
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid thin blue;
}
.sub2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: solid thin black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub1">I'm Div with auto width</div>
  <div class="sub2">I'm Div with 100% width</div>
</div>
```